# Compatibility between Scala closures and Java 8 closures

Tags: java, scala, closures, scala-java-interop

After reading some OpenJDK mailinglist entries, it seems that the Oracle developers are currently further removing things from the closure proposal, because earlier design mistakes in the Java language complicate the introduction of the Java closures.

Considering that Scala closures are much more powerful than the closures planned for Java 8, I wonder if it will be possible to e. g. call a Java method taking a closure from Scala, defining a closure in Java and giving it to a Scala function etc.?

So will Java closures be represented like their Scala counterparts in bytecode or differently?
Will it be possible to close the gap of functionality between Java/Scala closures?

Comment: I suspect we won't know for certain until closer to the Java 7 release

Comment: Not a real question. You'll certainly be able to use Java closures from Scala (and other languages) which is good thing for runtime operability. But Java closure are not specified so the details are not there yet.

Comment: @Thomas What makes you so certain, that Java closures are usable from Scala, considering that Scala closures are implemented as classes wouldn't that imply that Java would have to use scala's FunnctionX as argument types?

Comment: @soc - Thomas just means that, as all Java classes are usable from scala, so will the new ones. Probably

Comment: Looking at Java's attempt to evolve this feature, it looks very much like Java's approach to adding to solving a problems using the smallest possible feature is bad for the language's evolution. With a Scala/Ruby-like closure syntax, automatic resource management blocks (implemented as language syntax) would be unnecessary. If the language had generics from the outset, then array covariance wouldn't confuse the ability to add function types. If the language had closures from the outset, we wouldn't have so many different interfaces that we needed to convert closures to.

Comment: Should this question not be renamed to »Compatibility between Scala closures and Java **8** closures« — Latest I have heard and read on wikipedia is that closures have been purposed to Java 8. of course since closures have been in and out of Java 7 it is difficult to know for sure.

Comment: @Martin. Originally it was uncertain whether closures were on Sun's Java agenda. (In fact, it was becoming pretty certain that they were off the agenda). Then Sun announced that they were on the agenda because the Fork/Join framework needed them. That happened sometime last year.  A couple of weeks ago, Oracle decided that getting closures in Java 7 would delay Java 7 too much, so now Java 7 will be released soon(ish), and closures are postponed to Java 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: 5 years later, [SCALA 2.12.0-M3 (Oct. 2015)](http://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0-M3/) did include this enhancement:

> **Scala 2.12 emits closures in the same style as Java 8**.
>
> For each lambda the compiler generates a method containing the lambda body.
>   At runtime, this method is passed as an argument to the `LambdaMetaFactory` provided by the JDK, which creates a closure object.
>
> Compared to Scala 2.11, the new scheme has the advantage that the compiler does not generate an anonymous class for each lambda anymore. This leads to significantly smaller JAR files.

Answer (score 15):

I think it's more complicated than assuming there's two groups of stakeholders here. The [Project Lambda](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/lambda/) people seem to be working mostly independently of the Oracle people, [occasionally throwing something over the wall](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2010-July/002043.html) that the Project Lambda people find out indirectly. (Scala, is of course the third stakeholder.)

Since the [latest Project Lambda proposal](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2010-July/001775.html) is to eliminate function types all together, and just create some sort of fancy inference for implementing interfaces that have a single astract method (**SAM** types), I foresee the following:

- Calling Scala code that requires a Scala closure will depend entirely on the implementation of the `Function*` traits (and the implementation of traits in general) -- whether it appears to the Java compiler as a SAM (which it is in Scala-land) or whether the non-abstract methods also appear abstract to the JVM. (I would think they currently do look like they're abstract since traits are implemented as interfaces, but I'm know almost nothing about Scala's implementation. This could be a big hurdle to interperability.)

  Complications with Java generics (in particular how to express`Int`/`int`/`Integer`, or `Unit`/`Nothing`/`void` in a generic interface)  may also complicate things.
- Using Scala functions to implement Java SAMs will not be any different than it now -- you need to create an `implicit` conversion for the specific interface you wish to implement.

If the JVM gets function types (and Oracle seems not to have eliminated that possibility), it may depend how it's implemented. If they're first class objects implementing a particular interface, then all that Scala needs to do to be compatible is make `Function*` implement the new interface. If a new kind of type is implemented in the JVM entirely, then this could be difficult -- the Scala developers may wrap them using magic like they currently do for `Array`s, or they may create create `implicit` conversions. (A new language concept seems a bit far-fetched.)

I hope that one of the results of all of this discussion is that *all* of the various JVM languages will agree on some standard way to represent closures -- so that Scala, Groovy, JRuby, etc... can all pass closures back and forth with a minimum of hassle.

What's more interesting to me is the proposals for [virtual extension methods](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2010-May/001306.html) that will allow the Java Collections API to use lambdas. Depending on how these are implemented, they may greatly simplify some of the binary compatibility problems that we've had to deal with when changing Scala code, and they may help to more easily and efficiently implement traits.

I hope that some of the Scala developers are getting involved and offering their input, but I haven't actually seen any discussion of Scala on the Project Lambda lists, nor any participants who jump out to me as being Scala developers.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is great. The best thing imho would be if Oracle would just adopt Scala's FunctionX classes so that things are interoperable without any magic. But I guess they will try anything to just _not_ do that.

Comment: @soc: Scala's FunctionX classes work well for a number of Scala-specific reasions: (1) our type system hides the distinction between primatives and boxed types, and can fit `void`/`Unit` and `Nothing` into the type system naturally. (2) Definition-site covariance lets us easily pass `FuctionX`s in a natural way using only generics, and Java developers may feel the need to implement a radically new concept in their type system to implement this. (I think that's why Project Lambda is abandoning the idea of a function type.)

Comment: @soc: That said, I am disturbed by Project Lambda's apparent lack of discussion with other JVM constituencies.

Comment: Ken, the "problem" with FunctionX is that they are not single-method, which may cause problem as things stand. Also, not that there's no magic with `Array` in Scala since 2.8.0.

Comment: @Daniel, I'm kinda hoping traits like `FunctionX` can be implemented by public defender methods, then the JVM (which would know something about public defender methods) should recognize that there's only one unimplemented method making `FunctionX` a SAM. As far as `Array`: it still manages to appear in the Scala class hierarchy, and there are implicit conversions to wrap it with the usual `Seq` methods. If the JVM has real function types, the same thing can be done for those.

Comment: @Ken Just like `Int` appears in the Scala class hierarchy, but Scala's `Array` is fully Java's `Array` nowadays. Of course, there are implicits, but I wouldn't use the word "magic" for that, whereas it certainly could be used to describe arrays on previous versions of Scala.

Answer (score 7):

You would likely be able to do this extremely easily using **implicit conversions** *a la* `collection.JavaConversions` whether or not they come out of the box.

Of course, this is *not obviously so*, because it may be the case that Java closures are turned into types which get generated by the JVM *at runtime* - I seem to recall a Neal Gafter presentation saying something along these lines